# Nodejs and a few more basic questions

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

After a few weeks trying to explore Nodejs and its basic tutorials on the internet, I'm no more than just a Nodejs User. As I start to get into real self-program server, I encounter several problems which I tried to Google but no resources seemed to be helpful, so, yeah, I'm here to ask. Please help me understand these and be a node developer:

1) As I've experienced, there is **only 1 server file** `server.js` run through nodejs as server. Started as a PHP developer, I am not familiar with how it works, like, if you have, in term of PHP, process.php, rank.php, whatever.php which processes different tasks, I just need **to** send those data to according server file, but in nodejs case, I can only have 1 server.js file, then how can I ever **handle different tasks** from a single server file? Is there anyway to create more than just 1 server file? (I really don't want to mess up a single file with many parameters to perform different tasks and make the file size significantly big!)

2) Let's say, the first problem solved, now it leads to another problem. I've been trying some tutorials about database management, like mysql, or mail (which requires me to enter my Email password),... but as I notice, I entered **the password** required into a javascript file?!?!? I tried `localhost/server.js` and the file **is publicly available**... Is that something I really need to worry about?

3) Now as I advance further with familiarize myself with **nodejs** with php functions, such as mail, encrypting... I need to install different modules for different tasks, and I imagine one day if I host it online, I have to re-start installing those again? I am just wondering why there isn't any **standard functions** like in PHP. Of course, this is a personal question.

4) I would like to ask you please help me to throw a few lines of code (I just need it to the very basic) of how to send request, receive data like the code below does, but in nodejs. It would help me a lot in abstractly understanding how nodejs really works.

[index.html]

```
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php", //Which address should I send to if I use nodejs
    type: "POST",
    data: "p=test"
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

[process.php]

```
die($_POST["p"]);
```

-- With best regards and appreciation. Tim

Comment: "... how can I ever handle different tasks from a single server file? Is there anyway to create more than just 1 server file?" PHP's technique is the rare one. Most languages have a single point of entry.

Comment: Does it mean I need to pass an additional parameter to tell the server file what to do?

Comment: You can check out expressjs framework. You don't have to use it, but it shows how you can handle requests with different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Nodejs is a bit different then PHP. What you do there is to run a web server which takes the http request and process it. In the PHP world this is done by another server. Usually this is Apache or nginx, but that's not the PHP. So, what you should do is to use a framework like Express or write your own routing logic. For example:

```
var sendResponse = function(str, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(str + '\n');
}
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var url = req.url;
    switch(url) {
        case "/test": sendResponse("test url", res); break;
        case "/about": sendResponse("about url", res); break;
        default: sendResponse("default url", res);
    }
    sendResponse("test", res);  
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:1337');
```

In that example you parse the given url and execute a javascript function. You should organize your pages into modules and require them accordingly. So, if you run the code above you may type an url like 127.0.0.1:1337/about

2) Nope the file will not be visible. What it happens on your machine is that you have another server running. So, you actually open the javascript file as a static file. Stop your Apache and you will see that the file is not accessible.

3) That's the beauty of Nodejs. The package management system makes the installing easy and extremely flexible. You may use tons of modules and install whatever you want. This also gives you ability to build your own modules. In PHP there is no good central distributing system like in Nodejs, which makes difficult transferring modules from one project to another.

4) Here is a simple nodejs server:

```
var serverHTML = function(res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var str = '\
        <html>\
            <head>\
                <title>Page</title>\
            </head>\
            <body>\
                <h1>Page</h1>\
            </body>\
        </html>\
    ';
    res.end(str + '\n');
}
var serveAjaxData = function(res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end('{"data":"..."}\n');
}
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    switch(req.url) {
        case "/process": serveAjaxData(res); break;
        default: serverHTML(res);
    }   
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Just use the same approach like in point 1. And map a specific url which will return data to the ajax request. It's just a matter of routing.

In general there are a lot of modules, which could make your live easier. There are frameworks, which wrap the pure nodejs server, template languages, db adapters and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. This clarifies a lot. I was being misguided here. I got it to work now. Thank you VERY much!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. I think there are a few serious misconceptions here about how web servers work. Traditionally, running php on Apache will map all URLs to a corresponding script on the server's file system. However, most php web frameworks (Zend, Symfony, CakePHP, etc.) combined with `mod_rewrite()` rules will send all requests to a single controller which then routes those requests to the appropriate scripts based upon the request URL. [This is a good brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120411/1150652) of how it works with php. When you're using node.js and the default server/hello world example, this routing is not provided, which means you either need to build it yourself or use a framework (like express) to handle it for you. This is not much different from building a web application in php with one of the aforementioned frameworks.
2. Things like usernames and passwords should *never* be stored in plain text regardless of programming language. (Ideally, you'd have API keys as opposed to usernames & passwords as well.) There are a few ways to handle this, but the easiest way to do this is to set an environment variable in each environment (dev, QA, production) for API keys, usernames, etc.
3. Use [npm](https://npmjs.org). Create a `package.json` file to manage all of your dependencies. Then deployment should be as simple as running `npm install` in each environment.
4. This will depend on which framework you decide to use (if any) and I'd suggest looking at the corresponding documentation for examples of how to handle POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand one thing first..

Node.js and PHP are two very different ways of writing a web application.
PHP is a scripting language. The relevant PHP script gets executed by Apache (or any other server) after the server receives a request which looks like a PHP script. If it receives requests for other static files, it again tries to fetch them from the document root and serve them. PHP has nothing to do with this.

Node.js, on the other hand, **is the server**. It is very important to understand this. Running `node app.js` just starts executing the file. That is it. It won't even start a web server unless you want it to. That one file is now your server script. It doesn't execute or fetch other files unless you write it that way. Storing files in your node.js application folder doesn't automatically mean that the files are now accessible from the web, because the web server (if you have initialized one) isn't configured by default to simply fetch content from that directory. (There is a way to make a public web accessible directory easily in express, by the way).

This should answer your first two questions. Regarding your third question: You probably know this by now, but Node.js is essentially very low level. It does a few things, but does them very efficiently and very well. It is not a "one size fits all" tool like PHP which comes with several libraries.

I think the other answers help you with the 4th question. I just wanted to get this across to you.